# css of wrapper div

Tags: html, css

I am new to table less layout, recently designed website in table layout. Now converting tabular layout to table less layout.I am using a background image for website. I am having problem in wrapper div, i am giving wrapper div a background color and a shadow but it is not applying. Guide me where i am going wrong

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
background-image:url(../images/site-bg-5.jpg);
}

#wrapper {
width: 950px;
height:1500px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #FFF;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

I am having problem the wrapper div has drop shadow and border but it is of a specific height. i want the shadow & border height to auto adjust the height of the wrapper div. Show a working fiddle the correct way to do this.

Comment: so you need to show wrapped div to display body background

Comment: on your css " # wrapper " remove the space between # and wrapper

Answer (score 0):

There is a space between the "#" and the word "wrapper". Remove it and it should work.

This should be the final css:

```
body{
  background-image:url(../images/site-bg-5.jpg);
}

#wrapper {
  width:950px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-color:#FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`#wrapper` is correct

```css
body {
  background-image: url(../images/site-bg-5.jpg);
}
#wrapper {
  width: 950px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
df
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I am refering you to a jsfiddle. i am having problem that wrapper div is giving shadow and border to the header, menu and slideshow div. not giving the full wrapper div height.Somewhere i am doing mistake. plz point it out [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rizwan1969/4g34eosv/)

Answer (score 0):

try this css

```
body{background-image:url(../images/site-bg-5.jpg); }
#wrapper{width:950px;margin:0 auto;background-color:#FFF;box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;border:1px solid 000;}
```

Answer (score 0):

delete space between # and wrapper and it will work

also add `height`

Here is working fiddle:[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4vaf5f2b/)

Comment: problem solved but i want the box shadow and border to auto adjust the wrapper div height. is there any way to do this

Comment: add height:auto; and it will adjust according to div size.

Comment: If this solved your problem also accept it as accepted answer or reply to improve it.

Comment: got the point. I am refering you to a jsfiddle. i am having problem that wrapper div is giving shadow and border to the header, menu and slideshow div. not giving the full wrapper div height.Somewhere i am doing mistake. plz point it out Demo[link](http://jsfiddle.net/rizwan1969/4g34eosv/)

Comment: the style applies to wrapper div your wrapper div contains header.To which div do you want to apply box shadow?

Comment: as height is auto it is applying to all wraper div height and elements within

Comment: do you want to apply it to message div as well?

Comment: plz check my ref fiddle. it is only giving shadow and border to the header,menu,andslideshow div. the content div is not having shadow. if i give wrapper height 1000px then it covers the content div if height is auto then content div is not having shadow and border :(

Comment: yes. i want to apply it to message div as well and  content div

Answer (score 0):

See Demo here:[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JentiDabhi/xj11omur/)

```
#wrapper {
width:950px;
margin:0 auto;
background-color:#FFF;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
border:1px solid #000;
}
```